# how to take user input and assign to array

Tags: c#, arrays, matrix, assign

Say the user inputs a line "1 2 3 4", how do i assign it to an array such that at value of `array[0]` is 1, `array[1]` is 2 and so on? So far I only managed to assign values when the user presses enter after each value but not when the values are in a line, which is what I want to achieve.

```
double[,] array = new double[4,4];

Console.Write("Enter 16 digits: ");
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        array[i, j] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `split`?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2):

You have to split the line first:

```
string[] line = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
```

then its trivial

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        array[i, j] = double.Parse(line[i * 4 + j];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add something like

```
 var line = Console.ReadLine();
 var lineArray = line.Split(new Char[]{' '});
```

That will give you an array of individual string elements elements in lineArray, with "1" at [0], etc. If you then want to convert that to an array of doubles, you can do

```
var arrayOfDouble = lineArray.ToList().ConvertAll(x => Double.Parse(x)).ToArray();
```

Here's an explanation:

1. The split Method.  This is a method available for String objects.  It takes a string of characters (I just had an array of one element ' ', the space character) and splits the provided string on occurrences of those characters.  It returns an array of the split out items.
2. The call to ConvertAll.

   - This takes a function, in this case specified on the fly in lambda
     notation (i.e., the x => Double.Parse(x) bit), which allows
     specifying a function right then and there as needed. The function
     taxes a value, x, and tries to parse that value as a Double.  Since x
     comes from an array of strings, the type of x is String. The call to
     Parse tries to get a Double out of the passed string, x.
   - Because ConvertAll() is available on the List object, I first convert the array to a List via ToList().  The lambda gets called on each element of list, so every string in the original lineArray, will be passed to Double.Parse for conversion to a double.  A new list of Double will result.
   - At the end I make the resulting list of doubles back into an
     array via ToArray().